# maven variable refering to workspace directory

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Somebody knows a maven variable in order to refer to the workspace directory in the pom?
I know that ${project.build.directory} exists but I want to refer only to the workspace directory, not to include the name of the project.

Thank you very much in advance!

Regards

Comment: What about `${project.basedir}`

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I think the OP is looking for `${project.basedir}/../`.

Comment: What do you mean by `workspace directory in the pom`? Do you mean the folder where the pom file is located if so than `${project.basedir}` is the right choice.

Comment: No, the directory in which the project is being edited. All the path that is before the name of the project

Comment: This would be really helpful when dealing with a parent pom in order to reference locations dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as reference to the build workspace (as already mentioned in the comments):

```
${project.basedir}/..
```

However, while this should work in most environments, it depends a bit how your source is checked out. This approach assumes that checkout to exactly one directory (and not, for instance to `trunk/org.whatever.it.could.be`).